# Taking user input and alerting out an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-input

I'm trying to find out how many images are on a page using the DOM and store it to a variable. Once I find that I want to print out "There are VARIABLE (takes whatever the number is from the variable) images on the page." Next, to that, there will be a text box where a user can enter a number like 1 and the first image will pop up on another page (alert) when they click the Go button. I'm not sure what my code is doing wrong, but I'm confused. I know I need to append the button and textbox using jQuery.

What I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var image = $(.img).length;
  $(".numImg").click(function() {
    alert("");
  });
});
```

Full code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('img').attr('height','50px').attr('width','50px'); //make all images 50x50 pixels

    }); //end ready()

   $(document).ready(function() {
    var image = $(".img").length;
      $(".numImg").click(function() {
        alert("");
      });
    });

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="main_content">

    <div id="image_selection">
    <input type="text" value="Enter a number" id="imgNumber" > 
    <button class="numImg">Alert Image Selected</button>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div id="images">
    <h3>Some Images</h3>
        <p><img src="firetruck.jpg" alt="pic of truck" >  |
        <img src="baseball.jpg" alt="pic of baseball" >  |
        <img src="soccer_ball.jpg" alt="pic of soccer ball" >
        </p>

    </div><!-- end of 'images' div -->
    <hr>

    </div><!-- end 'main_content' div -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you missed a quote:

**Change:**

`var image = $(.img).length;`

**To:**

`var image = $(".img").length;`

Next:

> I'm trying to find out how many images are on a page using the DOM and
>   store it to a variable.

You've done this: `image` variable

> Once I find that I want to print out "There
>   are VARIABLE images on the page."

You'll need to put that text in the HTML first - then we'll address the rest

> Next, to that, there will be a text
>   box where a user can enter a number like 1 and the first image will
>   pop up on another page (alert) when they click the Go button.

Well, you cannot put an image in an alert.

Grab the images and refer to the index to use:

`var images = $('img');
 var requestedImageNumber = $('#imgNumber').val();
 var requestedImage = images[requestedImageNumber -1];
 window.open(requestedImage.src);`

This gets you started. There is a lot of to do. Please appreciate the fact that I'm keeping it simple so you can make progress.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can do the rest??

Answer (score 0):

Just a little correction for Randy's answer. If you want to select img element inside div.images you could do something like :

```
var imgCount = $("div#images p img").length;
```

Then use imgCount inside your alert :

```
alert("There are " + imgCount + " images on the page");
```

Comment: I don't want to alert the number of images, I want to print that statement next to my textbox on my page.

Comment: @fathur - granted - please realize I'm attempting to keep this simple for the OP by following the OP's style of code (use of `$('img')`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the missing piece. To insert new content on the page you can do this:

```
var image = $("img").length;
// Create a new <p> element and add the text to it.
var text = $('p').text("There are " + image + " images.");
// Insert as the first child of the #image_selection div
$('#image_selection').prepend(text);
```

Reference for [jQuery DOM manipulation functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

If you want to show the image in the same window instead of using `window.open` as proposed by @RandyCasburn, you could look into 'modal windows', but that is going to take some work.